# 502 bad gateway with Sails and SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx, sails.js, digital-ocean, dokku

I have a `sails` application that is hosted on `digitalocean` via `dokku`. Everying runs and deploys fine and if I havigate to my domain, I can see that the app is working.

Now I have added a TLS certificate (so that my app is accessible via HTTPS) by:

1. Creating my private key and CSR request.
2. Using them to get an certificate from CA authority.
3. Adding my private key and issued certificate to `config/local.js`
4. tarballing key and certificate and adding them to dokku via `dokku certs:add`

So after all that if I push my app to dokku it boots just fine without any errors upon deployment phase. I can clearly see that upon deployment my app should be accessible via https from buildpack logs:

```
...
-----> Creating https nginx.conf
-----> Running nginx-pre-reload
       Reloading nginx
-----> Setting config vars
       DOKKU_APP_RESTORE: 1
-----> Shutting down old containers in 60 seconds
=====> c302066ebd1ecc0ac5323c3cbbcaf9132eebf905f5616e5b4407cecf2b316969
=====> Application deployed:
       http://my-domain-here.com
       https://my-domain-here.com
```

The only problem is that when I navigate to my domain, I get "502 bad gateway" error in browser and if I look at nginx's error log of the app I can see the following errors there:

```
2016/07/14 03:09:30 [error] 7827#0: *391 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: --hidden--, server: my-domain-here.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:5000/", host: "getmocky.com"
```

What is wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured it out. It turned out that if you read closely about [deployment](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/deployment) in Sails you can see there a text like

> don't worry about configuring Sails to use an SSL certificate. SSL will almost always be resolved at your load balancer/proxy server, or by your PaaS provider

What this means is that from my list I have to exclude p3 and after that everything will work.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out. Please mark your answer as accepted for others that might have similar issues.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence I will, after 2 day timeout